# php ajax creating a search box like google

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, database

I want to create a search box, something like the Google search box.

I have a table in my database in which search texts are stored.

```
---------------------------
| searchdata     | output |
---------------------------
| id             | id=-1  |
| Data for id 1  | id=1   |
| data for 2     | id=2   |
| datatx id 2    | id=4   |
| datacv for id  | id=5   |
---------------------------
```

Now in my php file

```
<?php

        if ($con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","search")) {


          $chatData1 = $_POST['request'];


$textm= str_replace(" ", "%' or searchdata like '%", $chatData1);


          if (mysqli_connect_errno())
           {
               echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
             }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  search  where searchdata like '%{$textm}%' ");

if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo $row['output'];


}
 else{
echo "Please use English(US) Language.";

}


}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

For example if user types `data for id` the sql query must be like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM search  
WHERE searchdata LIKE '%data%' OR 
      searchdata LIKE '%for%' OR 
      searchdata LIKE '%id%'`
```

so it must give output acc. to table `id=1`, but it give me the output `id=-1`

Comment: Try reading about `MATCH()...AGAINST()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using [jQuery Ui Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), Only you need specify the field and showing your data with JSON

```
$data = array()
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  data[] = $row['output'];
}
// Outputs JSON
print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: and i want to print the data which match max

Comment: Check the "Remote datasource" example, there is your solution.